# Unable to delete cookies

Tags: php, session, cookies, methods

I am using cookies as a remember me function on my site. My method creates a number of cookies which works like a charm, however, I am unable to delete or change these values afterwards.

I create them by:

```
private function setCookies($userInfo) {
    setcookie("profileID",$userInfo["profileID"],time()+60*60*24*30);
    setcookie("userLevel",$userInfo["levelID"],time()+60*60*24*30);
    setcookie("username",$userInfo["username"],time()+60*60*24*30);
    setcookie("fullname",$userInfo["fullname"],time()+60*60*24*30);
    return true;
}
```

and my logout method:

```
public function logout() {
    session_destroy();
    setcookie("profileID","",time()-60*60*24*30*12);
    setcookie("userLevel","",time()-60*60*24*30*12);
    setcookie("username","",time()-60*60*24*30*12);
    setcookie("fullname","",time()-60*60*24*30*12);
    return true;
}
```

Both these methods are called within a controller file, before any output to the browser (head ect). What makes things worse is that it does not even change the values as list above to "" but remains with the original values.

Any ideas? I have not worked with cookies that much so this could be a simple error :)

Comment: Are you sure the logout() function is called? Try to put some echo or die statement in it.

Comment: try to set path to cookie '/', `setcookie(name, value, expire, '/');`

Comment: Any reason why you're using cookies in the first place and not session variables?

Comment: Yes, its particularly dodgy to store personal information in cookies

Comment: a) The logout() function is definately stored, tested with print_r, b) I'll try your answer devdRev, c) I am using sessions but using cookies for a "remember me" and storing minimal cookie info which I can then later just past back to the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the php manual for how to use session_destroy. It talks about cookies and how to destroy them.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

In order to use the same cookies again, you will need to call session_start() prior to doing so. You're calling session_destroy() and then trying to set your cookies.

Comment: I need info on deleting cookies. I am deleting session info as well thats why im using session_destroy. My question is related to the cookies, not session

Comment: Are you calling the logout function prior to any other output being generated by the script? This is a php requirement for setting cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies updated to a negative time or 0 time will get deleted only when the browser restarts if i'm not mistaken. Cookie expiration is managed through the browser's cleanup method that runs when the browser is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `session_unset()` before the `session_destroy()` in the logout method